# Will TCP header be present in IP fragmented packets

Tags: tcp, fragmentation

What happen when ICMP is disabled in an router and when packet size greater than MTU how the router fragments that packet?Will TCP header be present in IP fragmented packets?

Answer (score 1):

I don't test this scenario but ... I think that if the IP fragmentation is enabled, your IP packet data part will be fragmented and transferred independently because the fragmentation was used at L3 layer. Without ICMP, the sending computer don't know that the packet size is bigger than the allowed network MTU and it cannot send new fragmented data at L4 layer (TCP header will be presented in each packet). But we are fragmenting on L3 layer and we have to use fragment offset field. I think that the TCP header will be presented only in one packet, followed by fragmented TCP data part.

Try to make an experiment to test this behavior.